# does Windows Phone 8 support DirectShow filter?

Tags: filter, windows-phone-8, directshow

i'm going to develop a Media Player APP of WP8.
but i don't know WP8 supports directshow filter.
anyone knows?
thanks

Answer (score 4):

No it is not supported. You need to use Media Foundation like under Win8 RT.
Here is a Walkthroug to use MF on WinPhone8:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207074(v=vs.105).aspx